# How would i create a bookmarklet like the one provided with delicious

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bookmarklet

So a user would add a "add bookmart to the website" bookmark on their bookmarks and when they click it, a page would open and it would take the URL of the website that they were on when they clicked the bookmark...

If it matters, i'm trying to build the website on Rails, and i'm in very beginning stages, and i just wanted some ideas on how i would go about doing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a link to the Delicious Add Bookmark URL. To look at the Addresses for all of the sites, check out this [page](http://mark.kolich.com/2009/01/30/social-bookmark-sharing-urls.txt).

Replace this URL with the relevant information:

```
http://del.icio.us/post?v=4&partner=[partner]&noui&url={url}&title={title}
```

Partner is Optional.